# Repeat bracket insertion of auto_pairs_gentle with dot commmand

Tags: repeated-commands, plugin-auto-pairs

I have `auto_pairs_gentle` plugin installed and `vim-repeat` but the bracket insertion automatically generated by `auto_pairs_gentle` are not repeated by the dot command.

e.g.: Suppose I insert `f(x)` by typing `if(x<Esc>` if I repeat the command using the dot command `.` the only things that is inserted is `x`

Comment: A quick way: replace "\<Left>" by "\<C-G>U\<Left>" in the source code. (Also, no need for vim-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tpope/vim-repeat`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) plugin requires other plugins to support it by calling `repeat#set`, which [auto-pairs-gentle](https://github.com/vim-scripts/auto-pairs-gentle) does not.

Also, the plugin maps keys to `<C-r>=…<cr>` sequences in order to perform its actions. Some of those sequences involve moving the cursor (with <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>) or pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Insert mode repeat cannot handle these in the way you expect because

```
The following keys are special.  They stop the current insert, do something,
and then restart insertion.  This means you can do something without getting
out of Insert mode.  This is very handy if you prefer to use the Insert mode
all the time, just like editors that don't have a separate Normal mode.  You
may also want to set the 'backspace' option to "indent,eol,start" and set the
'insertmode' option.  You can use CTRL-O if you want to map a function key to
a command.
```

(from `:help ins-special-special`) includes arrow keys, and obviously <kbd>Esc</kbd> ends the current insert.

The repeat `.` command normally *literally* repeats the last insert, so it doesn't handle `<C-r>=` well anyway: for example, try `o<C-r>=localtime()<cr><cr><esc>....:echo localtime()<cr>`. Note that the buffer fills up with the same line repeated, while the function's value has changed.

For cases like this, use a macro (`:help q`), which records the keystrokes literally.

Comment: Thanks! I believe I'll give auto-pairs a try.

Answer (score 1):

In the source code of [auto-pairs-gentle](https://github.com/vim-scripts/auto-pairs-gentle/blob/master/plugin/auto-pairs.vim), we see that when an opening character is pressed, the [mapping returned](https://github.com/vim-scripts/auto-pairs-gentle/blob/master/plugin/auto-pairs.vim#L187) is

```
open.close."\<Left>"
```

ie, insert the opening char, followed by the closing char, and then move Left.

The arrow keys, including `<Left>` and `<Right>`, stop the current insert, move the cursor, and then restart insertion (as seen from `:help ins-special-special`).

This is why only the text inserted after the opening `(`, is saved into the `.` register.

One way to fix this is to replace `"\<Left>"` by `"\<C-G>U\<Left>"`,
which, further down in that help page, says that

> This makes it possible to use the cursor keys in Insert mode, without breaking
> the undo sequence and therefore using |.| (redo) will work as expected.
> Also entering a text like (with the "(" mapping from above):

> Lorem ipsum (dolor

> will be repeatable by using |.| to the expected

> Lorem ipsum (dolor)